# How can I prevent AccessDeniedException during Files.walkFileTree?

Tags: file, java-7, nio2

I'm trying to use Java 1.7 nio. When I call

Files.walkFileTree(source[i], tc);

where source[i] is any folder on my Windows file system and tc is a SimpleFileVisitor, I get an java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException. I've checked the folder and the folder contents and ensured that read, write, and execute are allowed for all users.

I can access the file fine using File. Why does walkFileTree have a problem accessing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. I overrode the visitFile method and it was incorrectly referencing a file path.